# changing on cakephp view flie (.ctp) but no changes in the browser

Tags: cakephp, browser, ctp

I have wasted more than an hour to deal with this view of CakePHP file. I am new on it. I am pretty sure i updated the correct file (only remove some part), but its not changing the view on the browser. Anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: you can check by removing Browser cache

Comment: can you share url and file name which you are editing

Comment: i am updating one of the ctp file in the view folder

Comment: what version of cakephp are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you've changed not the file you wanted. If you are using cakephp3 you should change the template folder either than view folder.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are clearing all browser cache. Chrome (for example) has it's 'feature and advantage' on the fact that keeps EVERYTHING in cache so the user finds everything running faster. This means suffering for development on a sleepy monday morning since you'll think nothing was saved or changed, until it finally decides to update it's cache and you've done 385 changes trying to fix it and don't even remember the version it should be on anymore. Clear the Cache or even config your browser to not save ANY cache if you develop in it.